# How does one say "suppose that" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would one say "Suppose that A?" I am looking for the way that this might be translated for mathematics.

Comment: More context would certainly be helpful.

Comment: We received a notice that multiple of your questions were closed. Please take some time to learn how to improve your contributions here. A first step would be to read the [tour] or go through the [help]. Please also take notice that the system may [ban questions automatically](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no literal translation for "Suppose that A" as a complete sentence that sound natural to me. The best I can do is "Man nehme an, dass A" or "Nehmen wir an, dass A". The first sounds somewhat stilted, the second depends on you being fine using "we" in your text (literally it's "Let's suppose that A", which some people are fine using and some aren't.)

You can alse use "angenommen, dass A" or "unter der Annahme, dass A", which both translate to "supposing that A". (If A is a formula, you could only use "angenommen": "angenommen P = NP".) Another thing that might be good situationally is "Sei A X", which translates to "Let A be X". It sounds weird to my non-mathematician ears, but I believe people still use it.

Comment: Is using "angenommen" as good/common as any of these options?

Comment: I'm assuming here that you don't literally write "Suppose that A", but that A stands for some longer proposition. In that case, I think it depends on whether a sentence or a formula follows. For a sentence, I would always use "angenommen dass A". For a formula, you could just use "angenommen": "angenommen P = NP" sounds perfectly fine. I'll edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Phrases using _Sei ..._ actually are standard for mathematicians. Examples: _Sei ω eine geschlossene Differentialform ..._ ; _sei N ein Normalteiler ..._.

Comment: @MartinPeters Thanks, I was unsure about that.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.mathematik.de/ger/information/fremdsprachen/typischephrasen.html

You could add more context around your phrase, then it would be more clear what your query refers to exactly, but I suppose you refer to an assumption that is invalidated as part of the proof.

Then you should use:

> Angenommen, *X* erfüllt *Y*; dann wäre .....
>   Suppose that *X* satisfies *Y*; then ..... would be .....